# Send a list of JSON data from one component to other in angular using customEvent

Tags: jquery, angular5

Here I looking to send some data which is binded in the event from one component to another using customEvent in bubbling technique. So I have worked on the code in which it doesn't work where I need some help

One Component Data:

```
  visibilityGrouping($event, data) {
    var elementData = [];
    if (data && data != null) {
      if (data.childRecords && data.childRecords.length) {
        data.childRecords.forEach(element => {
          if (element.childRecords && element.childRecords.length) {
            element.childRecords.forEach(child => {

              elementData.push({ eID: child.elementID })
            });
          }
          else {
            elementData.push({ eID: element.elementID })
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        // console.log(data.elementID);
        elementData.push({ eID: data.elementID })
      }
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('groupingElementIDs', { "detail": elementData }));
      console.log("elementData")
      console.log(elementData);
    }
  }
```

Another component data:

```
that.eventHandler = that.viewer._eventHandler;
        that.groupingSubscription = new FromCustomEvent(document, 'grouping')
            .subscribe((e: any) => {
                document.addEventListener("groupingElementIDs", (e) => {
                    console.log("event");
                    console.log(e);
                })

                document.dispatchEvent(selectionFired);

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Refer [Angular component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to select the method apt for you.

> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction